# Parse ACL that allows multiple roles - from another object - to have access to object

Tags: parse-platform, database-schema, acl, roles

This question is really made of two parts.

Using Parse, I'd like to have the following [simplified] scheme, where I have Users who are part of secret groups, and there are discussion that can appear across a few groups at one. That is Users who are part of `Group A` also are added to the `GroupA` role, and have access to discussions in Group A.

My trouble is, when I create a new discussion and tell it the groups it should appear in, how do I query for the roles and add them to the `Discussion` as well? I'm really fuzzy on this roles/ACLs business, even after reading extensively.

```
User(firstname, lastname)
Group(members, secrets)    
Discussion (groups, note, comments)
```

Comment: So your group has a pointer to the role? Or the role has the same name as the group? What's your data model like?

Comment: @Wain I haven't figured that part out yet either... I've got to figure out how to associate roles to the users and groups

Answer (score 0):

Create a Role when you create a Group. Assign a pointer from the Group to the Role. Set the ACL for the Group to the Role (for write, it can be public read or whatever you want). When you add users to the Group, add them to the Role so they have access through the ACL.

For your Discussion you need to add all of the appropriate Roles from all of the Groups to the ACL list so that all of the users in all of those Roles have access.